# Out, how do you calculate them?

Tags: poker-theory

**What are outs and how do I calculate them?**

I have heard this term tossed around by the big boys but I don't full under stand it. Is this the right place to ask? Anyway it would be nice to get a better understanding from someone who knows what they are talking about.

I know that they are the cards that will prevent you from complete annihilation but I've seen games where outs save someone even though the "outs" didn't rival the current best hand. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are numerous Q's on this site that cover what you are looking for Daedric. Try this link (http://poker.stackexchange.com/search?q=outs). I searched for "outs". I hope that helps. I'm going to close this Q as the information is already available. Perhaps the one closest to what you want is here, [Calculating Poker Outs](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4429/calculating-poker-outs).

Comment: @TobyBooth Thx anyway Toby.